# How to compile Javascript file into binary in Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, emacs, build

I am using Emacs, with flycheck, in Windows (unfortunately.).

Syntax checking is an critical component in writing code in Emacs. However the flycheck seems to require the user to find syntax checker by myself.

I was able to find syntax checker for html (html-tidy), which is written in C, and can be compiled into an binary and plug into flycheck mode and serves the purpose well.

Now I need to use Javascript, I found that most js checkers are .js files. So is there a way to compile them into binary, i.e. .exe file in windows?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's possible to compile JS into an executable, however, [JSHint](http://jshint.com/install/) does have Emacs support, including a [Flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck).